# Cayley tables- for any order $n$ there is some latin square with no orthogonal pair

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

How can we prove, using Cayley tables, that for any order $n$ there is some latin square with no orthogonal pair? What would this mean for the Cayley table regarding transversals? I am not entirely sure how Cayley tables work and hence am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Latin square can be regarded as the Cayley table of a [quasigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup).  Whether you talk about "quasigroups" or "Latin squares", is largely based on personal preference, and what tools you're planning on using.

A *transversal* is a selection on n cells in a Latin square that contains one representative from each row, column and symbol type.  In a pair of orthogonal Latin squares, the copies of any given symbol in one Latin square must correspond to a transversal in the other.

Latin squares without orthogonal mates are known as *bachelor* Latin squares, which exist for all orders except 1 and 3.  A slick proof was given by Judith Egan in:

> J. Egan, [Bachelor Latin squares with large indivisible plexes](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jcd.20281). J. Combin. Des. 19 (2011), no. 4, 304–312.

This is a non-trivial research problem, and prior work had been case-by-case.  Egan's proof was described as a "proof from the book" by her supervisor at the time:

> Wanless, Ian M.  Transversals in latin squares: a survey.  Surveys in combinatorics 2011, 403–437, London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 392, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 2011.